How to prevent the click event from a children not rendered by vue to bubble up to the parent
Link to codepen
The previous codepen allows you to resize vuetify table rows. Unfortunately with sortable: true the click event from the "hanlde" div bubbles up to the header row and triggers the toggleSort function from the default vuetify table headers. I don't want to override the headers slot so I cannot use @click.self="toggleSort", while adding e.stopPropagation() to the addEventListener doesn't work. Any idea?
You can notice the problem when you drag far enough to move the cursor outside of the div handle before releasing the mouse button. Here is a video: https://youtu.be/WsLPF-lpdDc

If dragging slowly and keep the mouse on the displayed blue bar, the problem won't appear

Just temporarily disable sorting when dragging:
--- a/app.vue
+++ b/app.vue
@@ -9,20 +9,21 @@
 <script setup lang="ts">
   import { ref, nextTick } from 'vue'

+  const sortable = ref(true)
   const headers = ref([
     {
       title: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
       align: 'end',
-      sortable: true,
+      sortable,
       value: 'name',
       width: undefined,
       maxWidth: undefined,
     },
-    { title: 'Calories', sortable: true, align: 'end', value: 'calories' },
-    { title: 'Fat (g)', sortable: true, align: 'end', value: 'fat' },
-    { title: 'Carbs (g)', sortable: true, align: 'end', value: 'carbs' },
-    { title: 'Protein (g)', sortable: true, align: 'end', value: 'protein' },
-    { title: 'Iron (%)', sortable: true, align: 'end', value: 'iron' },
+    { title: 'Calories', sortable, align: 'end', value: 'calories' },
+    { title: 'Fat (g)', sortable, align: 'end', value: 'fat' },
+    { title: 'Carbs (g)', sortable, align: 'end', value: 'carbs' },
+    { title: 'Protein (g)', sortable, align: 'end', value: 'protein' },
+    { title: 'Iron (%)', sortable, align: 'end', value: 'iron' },
   ])
   const desserts = ref([
     {
@@ -188,6 +189,8 @@
           divEvent: MouseEvent | undefined

         div.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
+          sortable.value = false
+
           divEvent = e
           curCol = (e.target as HTMLDivElement).parentElement as HTMLTableColElement
           pageX = e.pageX
@@ -252,6 +255,8 @@
             divEvent = undefined
           }
         })
+
+        setTimeout(() => sortable.value = true, 0)
       }

       function createDiv(height: number): HTMLDivElement {


It's a clever workaround, but removing the sortable prop on the whole table makes it automatically resize for big ones. It's good enough if you surgically disable the sortable prop on the leftmost column though. I will wait to see if someone can find the root cause of the problem, otherwise I will accept your answer. Thanks!
